# Multiple prefixes Discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

im working on my discord.js bot and it just got added onto top.gg and the prefix is Kei and people want to use kei or KEI how do I have multiple prefixes in 1 project

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your command handler?

Comment: Just lowercase the `message.content` property and compare it to the lowercased `kei`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your prefix variable is called `prefix`.

```js
var prefix = "Kei";

if(message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.content.startsWith(prefix.toLowerCase()) || message.content.startsWith(prefix.toUpperCase())) {
  //do something
}
```

In this example the code would run if the message starts with the prefix (`Kei`) **or** the prefix to lowercase, which means the prefix in lowercase letters (`kei`) **or** the prefix to uppercase, which means the prefix in uppercase letters (`KEI`).

So the prefix is the same only the letters change. You don't have to use multiple prefixes for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple thanks to JavaScript's native `.toLowerCase()` method. You can simply convert the message's content to lowercase and then check for the prefix.

e.g.

```
const prefix = "Kei";

client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix)) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the `message` event:

```js
const prefixes = ['!', '?', '/'];


let prefix = false;

for (const thisPrefix of prefixes) {
    if (message.content.startsWith(thisPrefix)) prefix = thisPrefix;
}

if (!prefix) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just simple.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    const prefixes = ['!', '?', '.'];
    let hasPrefix = false;
    prefixes.some(p => message.content.startsWith(p)) ? hasPrefix = true : null;
    if(!hasPrefix) return;
    //Start coding :)
}
```